# Correct way to count associated objects using JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, jpql

What is the correct way to write this JPA query? I am just guessing as I cant work it out or find it in my JPA book.

```
Query query=em.createQuery("select m from Meeting m where count(m.attendees) = 0");
return query.getResultList();
```

I am currently trying this with Hibernate and I get a mysql error!

```
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - You have an error in your
SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near ')=0' at line 1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To strictly answer the title of the question, use `SIZE`:

```
Query query=em.createQuery("select m from Meeting m where size(m.attendees) = 0");
return query.getResultList();
```

From the JPA specification:

> #### 4.6.16.2 Arithmetic Functions
>
> ```
> functions_returning_numerics::=
> ABS(simple_arithmetic_expression) |
> SQRT(simple_arithmetic_expression) |
> MOD(simple_arithmetic_expression, simple_arithmetic_expression) |
> SIZE(collection_valued_path_expression)
> ```
>
> The ABS function takes a numeric
>   argument and returns a number
>   (integer, float, or double) of the
>   same type as the argument to the
>   function.
>
> The SQRT function takes a numeric
>   argument and returns a double.
>
> The MOD function takes two integer
>   arguments and returns an integer.
>
> The SIZE function returns an integer
>   value, the number of elements of the
>   collection. If the collection is
>   empty, the SIZE function evaluates to
>   zero.
>
> Numeric arguments to these functions
>   may correspond to the numeric Java
>   object types as well as the primitive
>   numeric types.

In the particular case of `0`, you could also use `IS EMPTY`

> #### 4.6.11 Empty Collection Comparison Expressions
>
> The syntax for the use of the
>   comparison operator `IS EMPTY` in an
>   *empty_collection_comparison_expression*
>   is as follows:
>
> ```
> collection_valued_path_expression IS [NOT] EMPTY
> ```
>
> This expression tests whether or not
>   the collection designated by the
>   collection-valued path expression is
>   empty (i.e, has no elements).
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> SELECT o
> FROM Order o
> WHERE o.lineItems IS EMPTY
> ```
>
> If the value of the collection-valued
>   path expression in an empty collection
>   comparison expression is unknown, the
>   value of the empty comparison
>   expression is unknown.

I would test both to see which one is the most efficient (check the query plan).

Comment: Thanks Pascal, at some point I am going to have to sit down and memorise the JPA specification. It does help when you know what you are looking for.

Comment: @corydoras: You're welcome. And I can only recommend downloading the spec and reading it entirely to start with (it's not that big, some parts like the XML mapping can be skipped).